# GUI not correctly working

Tags: python, image, user-interface, audio, tkinter

I want to build a 30 second countdown clock, like in the TV show, with sound.

But when I run this code the sound plays and the GUI doesn't respond and so no clock comes up.

When I put 1 of the two parts in (clock or sound) they work, but it's when I implement them into 1 program it doesn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from winsound import *
import time
def count_down():
    # start with 2 minutes --> 120 seconds
    for t in range(30, -1, -1):
        # format as 2 digit integers, fills with zero to the left
        # divmod() gives minutes, seconds
        sf = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod(t, 60))
        #print(sf)  # test
        time_str.set(sf)
        root.update()
        # delay one second
        time.sleep(1)
# create root/main window
root = tk.Tk()
time_str = tk.StringVar()
# create the time display label, give it a large font
# label auto-adjusts to the font
label_font = ('calibri', 40)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=time_str, font=label_font, bg='black', fg='blue', relief='raised', bd=3).pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)
# create start and stop buttons
# pack() positions the buttons below the label
play = lambda: PlaySound('countdown_clock.wav', SND_FILENAME)
photo2=tk.PhotoImage(file="play button2.png")
tk.Button(root, image=photo2, bg='black', padx=2, pady=2, command=count_down and play).pack()
# stop simply exits root window
photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="stop button.png")
tk.Button(root, image=photo, bg='black', padx=2, pady=2, command=root.destroy).pack()

# start the GUI event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In tkinter programs, use root.after(milleseconds, function) rather than time.sleep(second).  Time.sleep blocks the event loop and makes the gui dead to user input.  If PlaySound does not block the event loop, it is because it returns immediately after setting up the file to be played in a separate thread or process.

Answer (score 1):

`count_down and play` will return `play`; consequently, `count_down` is not called when the button is clicked.

```
>>> a = 'a_truth_value'
>>> b = 'another_truth_value'
>>> a and b
'another_truth_value'
```

---

You need to adjust it to call both function:

```
tk.Button(root, text='play button2', padx=2, pady=2,
          command=lambda: (count_down(), play())).pack()
```

Comment: i changed the code to that and now it doesn't play the sound but plays after the countdown timer reaches 0. i want them to play at the same time. any help?

Comment: @NickP, In addition to that, you need to change `play = lambda: PlaySound('countdown_clock.wav', SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC)`

Comment: i made the changes you suggested and still the two parts are not playing together

Comment: Then, change the call order: `command=lambda: (play(), count_down()) `